# react-bootstrap-typeahead dropdown elements alignment issue with new version

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-typeahead

migrating react-bootstrap-typeahead from 3.2.4 to ^5.1.2, facing option element alignment issues, when i use 3.2.4 the dropdown works fine, just as expected

but with v5.1.2 instead of normal way, it looks like this
[image]

wanted it to look like below

[image]

like

```
abc
123
def
```

i have tried using this, but it doesn't give the look as before

```
renderMenuItemChildren={option => (
          <div key={option.id}>             
            <span>{option.text}</span>
          </div>
        )}
```

using the below of reference

```
"bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
"react-bootstrap-typeahead": "^5.1.2"

js
import { Typeahead } from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead'
import 'react-bootstrap-typeahead/css/Typeahead.css'
<Typeahead
              id="id"
              onChange={this.handleTypeChange}
              options={options}
              valueKey="id"
            />
```

Comment: Can you please post your code? Are you including the package CSS?

Comment: Be sure to also include the Bootstrap CSS

Comment: updated typeahead code, nothing fancy, normal typeahead...are you talking about importing bootstrap.css?, but i haven't imported bootstrap.css for v^3.2.4 it was working absolutely fine, then what is the need for importing bootstrap.css for the latest version?

Comment: we are using custom css for the page where typeahead is used, importing bs.css will completely change the alignment of the page, which didn't happen with older version and no bs.css

Comment: v5 of the typeahead dropped default support for Bootstrap 3, so if your custom styles are based on BS3, that may be causing the problem. Make sure your CSS are BS4-compatible, eg: the menu item should have the `dropdown-item` classname.

Comment: Hi @ericgio , sorry for the late reply, got it resolved by adding the css of typeahead in another css file and imported and worked fine, the reason i think it wasn't working because in the webpack i am removing the node_modules from the build from where i was importing the typeahead.css, i am not sure though the exact reason